# $f$ is increasing if and only if $f_{-}'\leq f_{+}'$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ has left $f_{-}'$ and right $f_{+}'$ derivatives. The claim is: $f$ is increasing if and only if $f_{-}'(x)\leq f_{+}'(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Only if: Suppose the hypothesis holds. Then $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)\leq f(x_3)$ for alle $x_1<x_2<x_3$ in $(a,b)$, and so the quotients hold
$$
\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\leq \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{x_3-x_1}
$$
This expression shows that
$$
y\mapsto \frac{f(y)-f(x_1)}{y-x_1}
$$
is increasing for any fixed $x_1$. So, letting $x_3\to x_1^+$, the expression on the right-hand side decreases and is bounded below by the left-hand sided. Thus the left-handsided is at most $f_{+}'(x)$. Similarly, for $x_2\to x_1^{-}$, the left-handsided increases and is bounded above by $f_{+}'(x)$. Hence $f_{-}'(x)\leq f_{+}'(x)$.

Is this proof correct? Can you help me with the converse direction, if the claim is valid?

Comment: The inequality between the quotients is wrong. The numerator on the RHS is bigger but so is the denominator. So the quotient might end up being smaller.

Comment: The inequality $f'_(x) \leq f'_+(x)$ simply tells that the 'wedge' at $x$, if exists, must be of the form $\vee$ (rather than $\wedge$), but otherwise it tells nothing else. In particular, it cannot tell anything about whether $f$ is increasing or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of the implications is true. In fact:

$$f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$x\mapsto -x$$

This map is strictly decreasing but it satisfies $$f'_{-}(x)\leq f'_{+}(x)$$(in fact they are always equal).

Now consider:

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} x  \text{  if }0\leq x\leq\frac12\\ \frac12 \text{  if }\frac12 \leq x \leq  1 \end{cases}$$

This function is increasing, but it doesn't satisfy your condition in $x=\frac12$.

Comment: +1. Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose the hypothesis holds. Then $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)\leq f(x_3)$ for alle $x_1<x_2<x_3$ in $(a,b)$, and so the quotients hold
> $$
> \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\leq \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{x_3-x_1}
> $$

This is not true, take for instance $f(x)=4x-x^2$ increasing on the interval $[0,2]$

$\begin{array}{|l}f(0)=0\\f(1)=3\\f(2)=4\end{array}\quad $ but $\quad \overbrace{\dfrac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}}^3>\overbrace{\dfrac{f(2)-f(0)}{2-0}}^2$

Therefore the remaining of your proof is invalidated.